# How to disable/override automatic mounting of tmpfs to /tmp by systemd?

Tags: systemd, tmpfs, tmp

**Background:** On my system `/tmp` is a regular part of the `/` partition and I use it for a few important features of the system.

**Current `systemd` Approach:** On new systems `systemd` has started to take over mounting and in particular, mounting a `tmpfs` over `/tmp` at boot or even during updates.  This is regulated in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount`:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Temporary Directory (/tmp)
Documentation=https://systemd.io/TEMPORARY_DIRECTORIES
Documentation=man:file-hierarchy(7)
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=!/tmp
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target
After=swap.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/tmp
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev,size=50%,nr_inodes=400k
```

**Problem:** A few months ago during an update some running processes started writing error messages because important files in `/tmp` disappeared - when `systemd` is updated even in a running system `tmpfs` is force-mounted over the existing `/tmp`.  It can also not be u(n)mounted ("filesystem busy").  This creates problems.

**Partial Fix:** I fixed it by commenting out the last 5 lines in the file given above.  Also, I removed `/usr/lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/tmp.mount`.  However, each time `systemd` is updated my customisation is lost - both files are no configuration files (though the `wanted` file should be a flag).  They will be replaced without warning.

**Question:**  How can I permanently disable the mounting of a temporary (or any) filesystem over `/tmp`?  Perhaps there is a `systemd` option I am missing?  I am looking for a solution surviving a `systemd` upgrade.

I did have a look at the manuals and linked documentation but nothing works.  I also tried

```
chattr +i /usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount
```

on my adjusted file but then `systemd` will not be updated at all which isn't an option of course.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks! My understanding was that `systemctl disable tmp.mount` removes the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/tmp.mount`.  Which symlink is created in `/etc`?  `strace systemctl disable tmp.mount` didn't reveal anything to me.

Comment: I did try disabling the unit in the past but it was reset by an update (or perhaps just ignored, don't remember).  That's why I ended up editing the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount` file.  I tried again now and will tell you after the next reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `systemctl mask tmp.mount` should do the trick for you: this will disable the unit, symlinking it to `/dev/null` in `/etc`, which will prevent its being re-enabled on upgrade. It will also prevent manually starting the unit:

```
# systemctl mask tmp.mount
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /dev/null.
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I trust it to work now (not tested yet but saw the new link).  Added the output for better searchability.