# How can I increase the size of /tmp directory without affecting RAM or anything else? (Redhat 8.2)

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, tmpfs, tmp

I'm new at Linux and I will get use of your help guys on this..
I want to increase the size of /tmp directory without affecting RAM or anything else on Red Hat 8.2 .. any suggestions to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable/override automatic mounting of tmpfs to /tmp by systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636843/how-to-disable-override-automatic-mounting-of-tmpfs-to-tmp-by-systemd) You'll need to reboot after that.

Answer (score 0):

`/tmp` can be either on RAM (tepfs) or on disk. You can find out where it is by using the `mount` command. Something like the below.

```
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
```

tmpfs indicates that it is on Virtual Memory (RAM)

It is possible to mount a disk (a partition) on `/tmp`, you can change its size without using more RAM. Please note that this can slow down applications that rely on a fast `/tmp`

If you decide to proceed.

You will have to create or have an empty disk partition.

Change the entry for `/tmp` from `tmpfs` to your partition on `/etc/fstab`

[Here is an article debating this](https://lwn.net/Articles/499410/)